# Color space conversion from YCbCr to RGB using PIL library?

Tags: python, image-processing, color-space, information-theory

How to do the following using python PIL library

- Converting from rgb to YCrCb and vice versa
- Creating images out of numpy arrays
- Merging y, cr , cb component back into ycrcb image

Answer (score 2):

from PIL import Image
rgb_img=Image.open("image_path")

rgb_image should be PIL image

```
yuv_img = rgb_img.convert('YCbCr') # to convert from YCrCb/yuv to rgb 
y, cb, cr = yuv_img.split() # to get individual components
```

To convert from YCrCb to rgb

```
if yuv_img.mode != 'RGB':
    rgb_img = yuv_img.convert('RGB')
```

To make image from array

```
    Image.fromarray(arr)
```

Merging y, cr , cb component back into ycbcr image

y, cr , cb should be images

```
merged_ycbcr=Image.merge('YCbCr', (y, cb, cr))
```